# Pub sub with REST API - the request is missing a valid API Key

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using the following code to do a test publish to `pubsub`

```
var data = {
  file: 'ciao',
  content_type: 'image/png'
};



needle
  .post('https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/topic:publish', data, {
      multipart: true
    },
    function(err, resp) {
      if (err)
        console.log('Error: ' + err.message);
      else
        console.log('OK.' + JSON.stringify(resp.body));
    });
```

But I get the error

```
{"error":{"code":403,"message":"The request is missing a valid API key.","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}
```

Do I need a service account authorized to `PubSub`? Any hint on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to verify the credentials you are using and the account permissions that those credentials have.

One of the popular approach is to have a `service-account.json` file with the credential information and use it as an enviroment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. You can get that file when creating a credential account for your pub/sub application. Examples on how to create that you can find it on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/authentication#service-accounts) under *Setting up authentication for server to server production applications.*.

Now you also need to verify the permissions and roles you credential account have. For cloud pub/sub there are lot of roles, like `roles/editor` or `roles/pubsub.editor` for the scope of your test run. You can even use a sample called [testing_permissions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#testing_permissions) from the official documentation to test your access. For a full lists of permissions and roles please see this [site](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles).

For more details you can check the [access and authentication](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control) page

Comment: Hello OuterSpace, have you managed to make it work?